# Aggregate number of distinct for group by subgroup

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a variable x, where I want to get the number of unique values in y conditional on those being unique to z.

Sample data:

```
df <- tibble(x = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2"),
             y = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
             z = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d"))
```

I can easily get the number of distinct values based on x and y:

```
df |> 
  mutate(
    xz_n_dist = n_distinct(y),
    .by = c(x, z)
  ) 

x         y   z     xz_n_dist
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>     <int>
1 A1        1 a             2
2 A1        1 a             2
3 A1        2 a             2
4 A1        1 b             1
5 A1        1 b             1
6 A2        1 c             1
7 A2        1 c             1
8 A2        1 d             1
```

But I don't know how to then add them up to the level of only x without double counting the distinct values within the z subgroups without dropping variables I need to keep and then summarizing. I could create a new table doing that then join back to the main table but it'd be nice to avoid that.

Desired results:

```
  x         y z     xz_n_dist x_n_dist
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>     <int>    <dbl>
1 A1        1 a             2        3
2 A1        1 a             2        3
3 A1        2 a             2        3
4 A1        1 b             1        3
5 A1        1 b             1        3
6 A2        1 c             1        2
7 A2        1 c             1        2
8 A2        1 d             1        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
df |> 
  mutate(
    xz_n_dist = n_distinct(y),
    .by = c(x, z)
  ) |>
  mutate(
    x_n_dist = n_distinct(y, z), 
    .by = x
  )
# # A tibble: 8 × 5
#   x         y z     xz_n_dist x_n_dist
#   <chr> <dbl> <chr>     <int>    <int>
# 1 A1        1 a             2        3
# 2 A1        1 a             2        3
# 3 A1        2 a             2        3
# 4 A1        1 b             1        3
# 5 A1        1 b             1        3
# 6 A2        1 c             1        2
# 7 A2        1 c             1        2
# 8 A2        1 d             1        2
```

Comment: And of course I didn't bother to check and see if I can just give n_distinct multiple vectors...thank you.